# Using Spring beans as a key with @Cacheable annotation

Tags: spring, caching, spring-el

How to make following to work: 
- a spring bean that has a method that should be cached with @Cacheable annotation
- another spring bean that creates keys for the cache (KeyCreatorBean).

So the code looks something like this.

```
@Inject
private KeyCreatorBean keyCreatorBean;

@Cacheable(value = "cacheName", key = "{@keyCreatorBean.createKey, #p0}")
@Override
public List<Examples> getExamples(ExampleId exampleId) {
  ...
```

However the above code doesn't work: it gives following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
    EL1057E:(pos 2): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'keyCreatorBean'
```

Comment: Try something like `#{keyCreatorBean.method}` instead of `@keyCreatorBean.method`.Just a random guess.

Comment: Somewhat related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749730/bean-creation-using-spel-hibernate

Comment: You may try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8142249/799562 `<cache:annotation-driven key-generator="myKeyGenerator"/>` but need to implement `org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator`.

Comment: I made a ticket about this issue to SpringSource: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9578

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5743565/1431 , here the problem is with Spring Security annotations, but the given workaround doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: As @biju-kunjummen has written down, the bean resolver is not set by the `EvaluationContext` used within the underlying classes. It would be possible but only by changing the implementation of `org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext` where the `EvaluationContext` is created. This may be a good hint to your JIRA ticket because that is the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the underlying cache resolution implementation, there doesn't appear to be a simple way to inject in a `BeanResolver` which is required for resolving the beans and evaluating expressions like `@beanname.method`.

So I would also recommend a somewhat hacky way along the lines of one which @micfra has recommended.

Along what he has said, have a KeyCreatorBean along these lines, but internally delegate it to the keycreatorBean that you registered in your application:

```
package pkg.beans;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public class KeyCreatorBean  implements ApplicationContextAware{
    private static ApplicationContext aCtx;
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext aCtx){
        KeyCreatorBean.aCtx = aCtx;
    }


    public static Object createKey(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        //store the bean somewhere..showing it like this purely to demonstrate..
        return aCtx.getBean("keyCreatorBean").createKey(target, method, params);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have a static class function, it will work like this

```
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName", key = "T(pkg.beans.KeyCreatorBean).createKey(#p0)")
@Override
public List<Examples> getExamples(ExampleId exampleId) {
  ...
}
```

with

```
package pkg.beans;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public class KeyCreatorBean  {

    public static Object createKey(Object o) {
        return Integer.valueOf((o != null) ? o.hashCode() : 53);
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to use a spring bean, not a static factory method.

Comment: Working with `@keyCreatorBean.createKey(#p0)` failed as it does in your case. Maybe the context is not aware of the bean instance at cache annotation processing time? Some spring guru around?