# Spring caching - How to reference a bean in SPEL to enable conditional caching via @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-el

I've got a method that I want to conditionally cache based on the result of a method call to another bean (which says whether or not global caching is turned on).

I've tried,using SpEL, something along the lines of

```
@Cacheable(condition="@someBean.isSomeBoolean()")
```

which requires a BeanResolver which I don't have configured. I'm OK about creating one of these programmatically but how do I configure the class I've got cacheable methods in to reference this ? The error I am currently getting is:

```
No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean
```

There's a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396911/using-spring-beans-as-a-key-with-cacheable-annotation) talking about keys, not conditions.

Has anyone successfully managed to reference other beans in caching annotations ?

Comment: i guess if you send someBean as a method argument then it can be easily referenced in condition ? have you tried that ?

Comment: I'll give that a go thanks. Obviously a pain having to introduce a parameter, but if it works, it works !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that someBean in a autowired bean in your class, you can use the object being invoked target to get it, try this

```
@Cacheable(condition="target.someBean.isSomeBoolean()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by writing a method on the class in question that delegates to another bean method call. Not ideal but works fine.